# C# asp,net project is working on IDE but after deploy on IIS getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

my C# asp.net application is working on my Visual Studio IDE but when same code deploys on IIS I am facing an issue of connection time out.
[image]

Comment: Make sure that you set valid site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Is this a ASP.NET Core app?  Keep in mind that the port VS uses is different the one in IIS.  You need to use the port IIS is listening on in the browser.

Comment: Ok, Let me check... thanks for help

Comment: Did you use enable https in Visual studio? If so, the project would return connection_reset when the default binding host header only use http. So please ensure your port can be accessed and security software won't block it. Then please try to add https binding for your website.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Comment: ok, thanks, I am sure it is not https.

Comment: What error message did you see in httperr log?

Comment: Thanks everyone for reply, I didnt get the actual reason for the error, I did fresh installion of windows and then redeply the application will reslove my issue